# Integration and maxima

Tags: calculus, integration

$$F(x)=\int^{x}_{0} \frac{t^2-16}{1+\cos^2 t}\,dt.$$ The problem says to find the local max of this expression. AFAIK, to take the max or min, I have to take the derivative of that expression. To do so, I plug in $x$ for the values of $t$. But how do I proceed after plugging in $x$ for $t$. Would I use the normal rules of differentiation, or something else?

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: I theoretically know the fundamental theorem of calculus, but the problem is how to apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$F'(x)=\frac{x^2-16}{1+\cos^2 x}$$
find where it can be zero.

> $x=\pm 4$.